# How can I test if my jar file has any unresolved dependencies?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, classpath, .class-file

I'm writing a custom tool to build jar files from our build tree. We like to build "minimal" jar files that contain only the `.class` files actually referenced from the "root" class (where main() lives) -- and so on, recursively following dependencies.

Historically we have done this by getting `javac` to follow source dependencies, but that means recompiling common files many many times. (We build 60 or 70 distinct application jars from a single source tree.) I'm writing a new build system that compiles each source file only once, but that means we need to follow dependencies by parsing .class files.

The good news is, I've got working code that does what I want. But I need to be *absolutely sure* I didn't screw it up, i.e. I want to ensure that I'm building internally consistent jar files, where "consistent" means that all unresolved references can be resolved with one of our known third-party jars.

So ideally I want a MagicTool that I can run like

```
MagicTool \
  --classpath commons-lang.jar:commons-collections.jar:[...etc...] \
  myapp.jar
```

that will examine every unresolved reference inside `myapp.jar` and make sure that it can be resolved by one of the third-party jars passed to `--classpath`. If not, barf.

Answer (score 2):

Better hope nothing in that path includes any sort of reflection, `forName`, etc.

I use [depfind](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) (if I'm not using my own Java spelunking tools) which may or may not provide output in a way that's helpful for you. [jdepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) is another option, although I've never used it for anything other than package-level dependencies.

Other tools like ProGuard will strip out unused classes (amongst other things), with the same reflective caveats.

I'm very wary of trying *too* hard to create minimal jar files; there's a point of diminishing returns/increased risk.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) is your magic tool, even if I don't now the exact call syntax.

Answer (score 1):

At one stage some years ago, trying to index a JAR file with `jar -i` made it throw an exception if there were unresolved dependencies. I can't quickly test the current state of things.